# ASP.NET Core how to override not valid value message

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-core, xss

I'm perfoming penetration tests with Acunetix and the following query "api/venues?gameId=1'"()%26%25vAtC(9571)" is getting the following response:

```js
{
    "status": 400,
    "userMessage": [
        "There are validation errors"
    ],
    "validationErrors": [
        "The value '1'\"()&%<acx><ScRiPt >NJMi(9780)</ScRiPt>' is not valid."
    ]
}
```

This is detected by Acunetix as a posible XSS security issue and I would like to override the validation error message in order to avoid this in the whole application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Model binder messages can be customized like this:

```
services.AddMvcCore().AddMvcOptions(options =>
{
    options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetNonPropertyAttemptedValueIsInvalidAccessor(s => "The provided value is invalid.");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Its worth adding that there are 3 other baked in binder errors, which display the value back, altogether:

```
options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetAttemptedValueIsInvalidAccessor((x, y) => $"The value is not valid for {y}.");
options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetNonPropertyAttemptedValueIsInvalidAccessor(x => "The value is not valid.");
options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueIsInvalidAccessor(x => "The value is invalid.");
options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueMustNotBeNullAccessor(x => "The value is invalid.");
```

Best to check MSDN ModelBinding message providers, for what's currently available.

Comment: This list looks correct based on the current documentation. For future readers, the message providers are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.metadata.modelbindingmessageprovider). The documentation shows the default error message for each provider.